# Searching through the draw.io map in "Read-only" mode throws "Error" - "v is undefined"

Tags: search, app.diagrams.net

I need to find an item "xyz" in a big technical map. At least the search done by the *Ctrl+F* "Find" box does not work:

[image]

> Error
> v is undefined

[image]

I am in the "Read-only" mode, therefore the "Find" box is that small. In the mode with all of the rights, it is a "Find/Replace" box instead, and the search works:

[image]

How can I search for an item in another way in a "Read-only" mode, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround that I see up to now is already hidden in the question: copy the file to have all of the rights. Then, you can search.